# plotting stacked bar graph on column values

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a Pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
ID  Management   Administrative
1      1              2
3      2              1
4      3              3 
10     1              3
```

essentially the 1-3 is a grade of low medium or high. I want a stacked bar chart that has Management and Administrative on x-axis and the stacked composition of 1,2,3 of each column in percentages.

e.g. if there were only 4 entries as above, 1 would compose 50% of the height, 2 would compose 25% and 3 would compose 25% of the height of the management bar. The y axis would go up to 100%.

Hope this makes sense. Hard to explain but if unclear willing to clarify further!

Comment: It is very unclear to me as I can't see the relation of your explanation to your dataframe. To me, for index 1, Management would compose for 33% and Administrative 66% for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to chain several operations: First `melt` your dataset to move the `Department` as a new variable, after that you can `groupby` the `Department` and the `Rating` to `count` the number of IDs that fall into that bucket, then you `groupby` again by `Department` to calculate the percentages. Lastly you can `plot` your stacked bar graph:

```
df4.melt().rename(columns={'variable':'Dept', 'value':'Rating'}
    ).query('Dept!="ID"'
    ).groupby(['Dept','Rating']).size(
    ).rename('Count'
    ).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x/sum(x)
    ).unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]